# componentsProps -> slotProps change and codemod

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a little bit of DataGrid code using the now-deprecated components and componentsProps.

I was getting a warning about that from tsserver (in neovim), but am no longer.  I'm not sure what that's about - are components and componentsProps being deprecated less aggressively now?

Also, I decided to try the codemod to fix it, as described at https://mui.com/x/migration/migration-data-grid-v5/ which suggests:

```
npx @mui/x-codemod v6.0.0/data-grid/rename-components-to-slots <path>
```

So I ran it and got:

```
$ npx @mui/x-codemod v6.0.0/data-grid/rename-components-to-slots src/components/PlatformDataGrid/PlatformDataGrid.tsx
below cmd output started 2023 Wed Nov 29 03:43:43 PM PST
Executing command: jscodeshift /data/home/dstromberg/.npm/_npx/a9b616de167a2c5b/node_modules/jscodeshift/bin/jscodeshift.js --transform /data/home/dstromberg/.npm/_npx/a9b616de167a2c5b/node_modules/@mui/x-codemod/v6.0.0/data-grid/rename-components-to-slots --extensions js,ts,jsx,tsx --parser tsx --ignore-pattern **/node_modules/** /data/home/dstromberg/src/publishing-jiras/GPDT-1838-Deprecated-variables-in-game-publishing-tact-client-could-lead-to-broken-code/game-publishing-tact-client/src/components/PlatformDataGrid/PlatformDataGrid.tsx

====================================
IMPORTANT NOTICE ABOUT CODEMOD USAGE
====================================
Not all use cases are covered by codemods. In some scenarios, like props spreading, cross-file dependencies and etc., the changes are not properly identified and therefore must be handled manually.

For example, if a codemod tries to rename a prop, but this prop is hidden with the spread operator, it won't be transformed as expected.
<DatePicker {...pickerProps} />

After running the codemods, make sure to test your application and that you don't have any console errors.

Processing 1 files...
Spawning 1 workers...
Sending 1 files to free worker...
All done.
Results:
0 errors
1 unmodified
0 skipped
0 ok
Time elapsed: 0.607seconds
```

Why is the codemod "not modifying" the file that definitely has components and componentsProps in it?

```
$ grep component src/components/PlatformDataGrid/PlatformDataGrid.tsx
below cmd output started 2023 Wed Nov 29 03:44:45 PM PST
    components = {},
    componentsProps = {},
            components={{
                ...components,
            componentsProps={{
                ...componentsProps,
```

Thanks!

Comment: I went ahead and fixed the problem manually, but I remain curious.